# Elasticsearch: How to delete unsupported static index setting created by a previous release?

Tags: elasticsearch

How to delete static settings from an index if this setting is not supported/known anymore to the running ES version.

Indices created with ES 5.2.2 or 5.3.0 have been subject to shrinking with a hot-warm strategy in order to lower the number of shards.
This shrinking created two static index settings `shrink.source.name` and `shrink.source.uuid` in the newly created index.

The new index works as expected.

In the meantime I upgraded to ES 6.8.1 and I am preparing the Elasticsearch cluster for ES 7.0 as indices created with older versions are not supported anymore with ES 7.0.

Kibana offers a nice UI for the required reindexing but this fails due to these two unsupported setting.

As I have no need for these settings anyway (they are just informational for me) I want to delete them from the indices.

Deleting a static setting from an index requires the follwing steps:

1. close the index
2. set the setting to null
3. reopen the index

Unfortunately this does not work with settings which are not supported *anymore* with the current version of ES.

```
curl -X PUT "elk29:9200/logstash-20160915/_settings?pretty" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d' { "index" : {   "shrink.source.uuid" : null }}'
{
  "error" : {
    "root_cause" : [
      {
        "type" : "remote_transport_exception",
        "reason" : "[elk24][10.21.15.24:9300][indices:admin/settings/update]"
      }
    ],
    "type" : "illegal_argument_exception",
    "reason" : "unknown setting [index.shrink.source.uuid] please check that any required plugins are installed, or check the breaking changes documentation for removed settings"
  },
  "status" : 400
}
```

I expected that the setting is simply removed.

Oviously ES emulates the removal of a setting by setting the value of a setting to `null`. Unfortunately this only works with explicitly supported settings but not with outdated unsupported settings.

The question remains how to remove index settings which are not supported anymore with the current version of ES?